# Time Constraint Trigger on Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm a total noob on SQL, but I'm doing a project where I have a database of a Football League and I want to create a constraint trigger that is:  a referee can only be associated to one match at a time, and can also only be associated to a match every 3 days.

```
CREATE TABLE Ref
  (
    RefID              INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    Refname             VARCHAR2 (80) NOT NULL ,
    RefFunction_FuncRefID INTEGER NOT NULL
  ) ;

CREATE TABLE RefParticipates
(
    Ref_RefID INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    Game_GameID       INTEGER NOT NULL
  ) ;

ALTER TABLE RefParticipates ADD CONSTRAINT RefParticipates PRIMARY KEY ( Ref_RefID, Game_GameID ) ;
```

Comment: Can you share an input table(s) with us?  Have you any of your own ideas?

Comment: the first can be done, the second (every 3 days) is business logic, and likely not to be solved by a trigger (at least that would not be what triggers are for). Post schema and code, otherwise you won't get many useful answers here.

Comment: @dlatikay That can be done quite easy `select count(refree) into c from table where assign_date > sysdate - 3 and refree = r` and then `if c > 0 then raise`. But as others said please edit your question and add tables you have and describe relations. It is hard to give you any hint without nowledge about your DB structure

Comment: added table, don't know if it helps

Comment: @Kacper what do you mean by "c"?

Comment: @dood added tables, if you want another one tell me, thanks in advance

Comment: Variable that is `number`. It was just an example to show diatikay that it is possible to check time constraint in trigger.